# Django - No module named 'webapp'

Tags: python, django

[image: Project Structure]

**Settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'webapp',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

**Apps.py**

```
class WebappConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'webapp'
```

**Error**

```
C:\Users\agent\PycharmProjects\ExampleProj\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\agent\PycharmProjects\ExampleProj\mysite\manage.py createsuperuser 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\agent\PycharmProjects\ExampleProj\mysite\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\agent\PycharmProjects\ExampleProj\mysite\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\agent\PycharmProjects\ExampleProj\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\agent\PycharmProjects\ExampleProj\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 420, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\agent\PycharmProjects\ExampleProj\venv\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\agent\PycharmProjects\ExampleProj\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "C:\Users\agent\PycharmProjects\ExampleProj\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 193, in create
    import_module(entry)
  File "C:\Users\agent\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'webapp'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Am I missing something here? Same result when using mysite.webapp... I included the traceback as requested.

Comment: Also, please enlighten me on the correct project structure if I was to include many others apps. I need help for best practices.

Comment: Can you share the full error traceback?

Comment: Yes! I will edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, lets start with the structure, it is a bit weird. Looks like you created a directory called `mysite` for your Django project, which is not necessary.

`webapp` is not a module, but the root project app. Which is very confusing because it should be named the same as your root folder (`mysite`)  if you used `django-admin startproject mysite`.

If you want to maintain the current structure (which I do not recommend), you need to modify a few files:

asgi.py and wsgi.py

```py
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'webapp.settings')
```

settings.py

```py
...
ROOT_URLCONF = 'webapp.urls'
...
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'webapp.wsgi.application'
...
```

And remove `webapp` from `INSTALLED_APPS`.

#### Alternatively

I recommend that you start from scratch. Delete `mysite` folder entirely. Then, from within `ExampleProj` folder where your venv is located, activate your virtual env and:

```
django-admin startproject mysite
```

That will start the initial structure correctly, and then to create an app:

```
cd mysite
python manage.py startapp webapp
```

`webapp` is now a module to be added at `INSTALLED_APPS`.